# How to add "hours" and "minutes" words with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following time 
`moment.utc(data.item.timeInSeconds * 1000).format("HH:mm")`. it displays the time in `00:00` format but is there a way to add `00 hrs: 00 mins` using moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the extra words with []

`moment.utc(data.item.timeInSeconds * 1000).format("HH [hrs]:mm [mins]")`